# Cannot read cookies with cookie-parser in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, jwt

I have a angularjs frontend and nodejs backend in my project. In angular code im setting a cookie using $cookies object and its working fine, cause i can find the cookie in "Show page info" on the top left corner of the browser. However when im sending get request to the backend i cant read that cookie there. I have those lines in my server.js: `const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');` and later `app.use(cookieParser());`. 
Then im trying to do this:

```
//custom passport jwt extraction function
var cookieExtractor = function (req) {

    console.log(req.cookies); //logs a '{}'

    var token = null;
    if(req && req.cookies)
    token = req.cookies['jwt'];
    return token;
};
```

And here the problem occurs, because the cookies object is empty (i'm getting '{}' in the console). What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I'm attaching a ss of browser's cookies set by my app (sorry for non-english language): [cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfFMi.png)

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: Yes, i do use express

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

if you want set a cookie as string use put method.

and you want set a cookie as object use putObject method.

**Angularjs**

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Hello world";
  $cookies.putObject('myCookie', obj);
}]);
```

**nodejs**

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(cookieParser());
}

console.log('cookie', req.cookies.myCookie);
```

Comment: I still cant get access to the cookie on the server side. The req.cookies.myCookie is undefined.

Comment: Please verify the cookie is present your browser application

Comment: As i said before. The cookies are present in browser. I just cannot access them in nodejs (i can in angular tho). May the cookies path set to "/auth" be a problem here? Its a path where i have my angular app set up.